# Division by zero in the Neyman–Pearson lemma

Tags: maximum-likelihood

I understand that in theory the Neyman-Pearson lemma gives the most powerful test for a prescribed level, when we have a simple null hypothesis against a simple alternative. However, when I try to apply it in the following situation, the problem is that I get a division by zero, so I'm doubly-stuck: (1) I don't know if the lemma applies at all in this case, I would say yes, as there are no such restrictions in the statement; (2) still I can't see how to formulate the test, i.e. how to define the rejection region.

Here is my situation:

*We draw n times from the uniform distribution on $(0,\theta)$.*

$H_0$: $\theta=\theta_0$

$H_a$: $\theta=\theta_a$

*We need to find the most powerful test at level $\alpha$. (Suppose it's also known that $\theta_a<\theta_0$)*

If I apply the lemma directly, I see that for a given sample I can get that either the denominator or both likelihoods simultaneously become zero.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, this is an easy one. I just had a look at the proof of the NP lemma, in order to understand better what's going on. And the solution was suddenly clear. We have $\mathbb R^n$ and we consider two measures on it, $m_0$ and $m_a$, induced by $H_0$ and $H_a$, respectively. Our RR should be a subset that is as small as possible under $m_0$ (so as to minimize the type I error) while at the same time being as large as possible under $m_a$ (in order to maximize the power). Now since in this case the supports of the two measures are two hypercubes, one subset of the other, namely $[0,\theta_a]^n\subset [0,\theta_0]^n$, we simply choose for the RR the hypecube $[0,t]^n$, where $t=\min\{\theta_0\sqrt[n]{\alpha},\theta_a\}$.